# How to run PHP with the user permission on apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

As the title, I have many vhosts, how Can I run PHP with the user's permission ?

```
website1 --> user1:user1
website2 --> user2:user2
website3 --> user3:user3
```

I have read suphp, but it is extremely slow I have read 25 times slower the mod_php.

Can I do it differently?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for [this](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/).

*mpm-itk allows you to run each of your vhost under a separate uid and gid*

Comment: @Chris ok, but run vhosts with separate uid and gid also means that php will run with these permission ?

Comment: @Chris then... does it degrade the performance of the server?

Comment: @Damiano: Yes php runs with those permissions, however I can't comment on the performance. I run it at my company and we haven't noticed anything, but we don't get a whole lot of traffic.

Comment: @Damiano: also it depends on what you mean by performance. If you mean apache's performance, then yes possibly, if by a very small amount. If you mean php, I can't imagine how it would degrade php's performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP though FastCGI instead of using mod_apache. There's some good information on [this page](http://www.seaoffire.net/fcgi-faq.html)

Comment: I believe this is what suPHP does, and yes, it's slow as hell!

Comment: No, suPHP uses plain old CGI - FastCGI does not involve process creation on each request and is not slow.

Comment: http://php-fpm.org/ is a new FastCGI implementation and is quick with some other nice features thrown in.